# Using constants inside perl pack/unpack template strings

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use constants in `pack()` and `unpack()` templates ?

I've had a quick look through the docs (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and whilst I see you can use standard variables (i.e. `$foo $bar`), I can't see any reference to using constants.

For the downvoters: I meant ***INSIDE*** the template....

e.g. instead of `pack("a$civ a*......"` use a constant instead of `$civ`

Comment: Constants are just functions in Perl. They return values. Try it. It will work.

Comment: @simbabque See later comment. I meant INSIDE the template, not a constant as a template !

Comment: I have not cast a vote yet. I think the question is not bad, but didn't have enough information. It now has more, which is good.

Comment: So, you are just asking how to interpolate a compile time constant produced using `use constant` into a string ... That really does not have anything to do with `pack`/`unpack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may you `Const::Fast` module.

```
use Const::Fast;
const my $foo => 'a scalar value';
print "X${foo}X\n";
```